# Installing Innodb plugin

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to install the InnoDb plugin for mysql 5.1.61, I have successfully done this in the past on a slightly older version of mysql (less than 5.1.38) however I am currently trying to do this on 5.1.61.

Apparently the Innodb plugin is [no longer available](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-plugin-installation-overview.html) for download and instead is [bundled in with the download](http://www.innodb.com/wp/2010/04/26/innodb-plugin-1-0-7-ga-has-been-released/) of the server from MySQL.

After installing the RPMs available on the Mysql 5.1 download page I have attempted to enable the innodb plugin as described on the mysql site by adding the line [ignore_builtin_innodb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-plugin-installation-configuration.html) into the configuration file but all this does is disable innodb completely.

I have noticed that there is no file called `ha_innodb.so` anywhere on the server after instillation so it appears that the plugin is not bundled with this version of mysql now as is claimed, or at least its not bundled in the download direct from mysql.

Does anyone know if there is something I am missing, or if the innodb plugin is available for download independently of the mysql distribution that I can install manually?

Comment: I never needed to install it as a plugin. Just downloaded the mysql and there it is. Which is your OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a known problem as the InnoDB Plugin is not built for RedHat 3, 4, SuSE 9 or for Generic Linux for 5.1 and must be built manually which I am not prepared to do. I have instead decided to bite the bullet and upgrade to MySQL 5.5 where the InnoDB Plugin in now the built in InnoDB driver.

See this bug report for more
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47294

Comment: I am facing the same issue with mysql 5.5?What is the solution for it?

Comment: @JerwinRoy I don't believe this is an issue for 5.5 as the InnoDB plugin improvements were integrated into mysql in v5.5

Comment: I needed it as `innoDB plugin` for mysql 5.5,So i am trying at the file ha_innodb.cc avaliable at mysql-5.1.61/storage/innobase/handler/ and v can create an ha_innodb.so for that file.Am i right?